# Rest API not working for real state property for post type in WP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I try to post the real state property data using rest API in WP(word press) then,

"property title" and "property content data" fields are created in  **"wp_posts**" table but the functionality  to create other property fields(attribute) in **"wp_postmeta"** table is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`register_post_type` function set argument

`'show_in_rest' => true,`

Setting this argument to true will add a route in the wp/v2 namespace

Comment: I added 'show_in_rest' => true, in  register_post_type,still I am not able to get property fields(attribute) in "wp_postmeta" table